# Why do I get connection timeouts to private services in Azure?

Tags: tcp, azure, timeout, service

I seem to be seeing this with both my SQL Server, and my MongoDB replica set.  I only get a handful a day, but it still concerns me.

I am getting a timeout when trying to open a new connection to the remote system.  This happens even when the remote system is up and responding.  I have a single SQL Server instance and a 3-system mongodb replica set.  It seems to happen rather sporadically under moderate to higher loads.

I'm using connection pools, and the sizes should limit connections (per process of course), neither should be seeing over 1k connections, just the same I'm seeing timeouts attempting to connect.

The SQL server is windows (of course), the mongodb instances are under Ubuntu, and the clients are a combination of node.js under linux and windows, as well as .Net 4.5 applications.

I'm in the process of creating a more resilient (try 3 times before fail) architecture, just the same the issue concerns me.

What would you look for in terms of issues here?

Comment: I have the same problemen. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Question is old and this might be a different root problem, but since i spent more than a week tracking it down and it might save someone time here goes:

I am having a problem that presents a similar error. after digging in together with azure tech support their best guess (they are **not sure**) is that idle connections get killed by some proxy between the web apps and the server. this happens after about 4 minutes. and in such a way as both server and client have no idea it is happening. when you try to use the connection in that state the client sends packets that never make it to the server.

Last I heard this is not going to be changed/fixed. so the options to prevent this (in order of sanity) are :

1. kill idle connections on the server at the ~3 minute mark.
2. set the client to kill the connection if it is idle at the ~3 minute mark.
3. make sure you don't have idle connections by doing some busy-work on the client.

your try again if connection fails will work if it will actually create a new connection, if not it's just going to make the app wait longer before coming to the same point.

I will update in a week if this actually fixes the problem for good.

edit:
A combination of killing idle connections on the client and sending a keep-alive from the server every 2 minutes made this problem go away.